# How to clear last generated table with new one on radio select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a module with 3 radio buttons. Clicking one radio button lists data related to it and so on. I have applied ajax call on radio buttons click and return an array in the response. My problem here is for each radio button click the data keeps on adding into the list. For e.g. if I click on 'All users' radio it displays the data related to "All" but again if I click on "Unapproved Users" radio, the list adds up to the 'All users ' listing at the bottom. So how can I reset the $_POST variable each time the data is rendered so that new list appears for new radio selection, I would really appreciate the help or advice for this.

```
 <script>
        $('#selection').change
        (

            function() 
            {
              var selected_value = $("input[name='users']:checked").val();
              //till here the code works fine.
$.ajax
                ( 
                    {
                        url: "approval_ajax.php",
                        dataType : "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        data: { selected_value : selected_value },

                        success: function(response)
                        {
                             console.log(response);
                                var len = response.length;
                           for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                                 var id = response[i].id;
                                 var email = response[i].email;
                                 var employee_id = response[i].employee_id;
                                 var first_name = response[i].first_name;
                                 var middle_name = response[i].middle_name;
                                 var last_name = response[i].last_name;
                                 var mobile = response[i].mobile;
                                 var created_on = response[i].created_on;
                                 var disabled = response[i].disabled;

                    var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + first_name + "&nbsp;" + middle_name + "&nbsp;" + last_name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + created_on + "</td>" +
                        "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'"  + disabled +  "value= '"  + id +  "' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" +
                          "<input type='hidden' value='"  + id +  "' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" +
                        "</tr>";

                    $("#example").append(tr_str);
                }
                           alert("AJAX was a success");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
```

**approval_ajax.php**

```
session_start();

require("../includes/config.php"); 
require("../classes/Database.class.php"); 
$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);  

$return_arr = array();
$status=''; 

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
   {
       $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "selected_value");


       if (isset($value))
       {
         $users=$value;

}else{
    $users='';
}

switch ($users)

{

case "all":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";       

break;

case "approved":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";   
break;

case "unapproved":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =0";   

break;

}

$sq = $db->query($sqlQuery);


if ($db->affected_rows > 0) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
    $disabled = '';
    if ($status == '1') {

        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
    }

    $id = $row['id'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $mobile = $row['mobile'];
    $created_on1 = $row['created_on'];
    $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on1));

    $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
    "email" => $email,
    "employee_id" => $employee_id,
    "first_name" => $first_name,
    "middle_name" => $middle_name,
    "last_name" => $last_name,
    "mobile" => $mobile,
    "created_on" => $created_on,
    "disabled" => $disabled
    );
}
}
header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An append() jQuery function adds html content to requested element. In your case, you want to refresh users list on click of radio select. You need to use html() jQuery function to clear old result and add new result to requested element.

So please modify following line of your code:

```
$("#example").append(tr_str);
```

to

`$("#example").html(tr_str);`

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time . I used it , found to display only one record, the last one from each table. Rather I used <tbody id='datashow'> and then it worked. But still where I am stuck is the list being generated for each radio does not takes the classes applied on table for pagination. Can you help me over this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557108/how-to-apply-table-classes-to-returned-json-response Please check this one.